# Extending holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Assume f is an analytic map of rectangle $R$ onto another rectangle $ S $ which maps each side of $ R $ onto a side of $ S $. Then $ f $ can be extended analytically across the sides of $ R $, mapping rectangles adjacent to $ R $ ontno rectangles adjacent to $ S $. Continuing in this manner, $ f $ can be extended to an entire function.

I saw this suggetion in my book of complex analysis. The author explains that its easy to see. But Im not sure how exactly the extension occurs. Also, on which theorems we rely when we prove this suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know Schwarz reflection principle? Maybe there's an easier method, but I think it should be possible to adapt your function so it fits into this.

Comment: He may refers to [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation), which states than any analytic function defined on an open set can be uniquely extented to an analytic function on $\mathbb{C}$ (although I can't tell for sure without the context).

Comment: @PaulK I think that the author ment to use a generalization of Schwartz reflection principle as suggested here : http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~pebenfel/EHuang_refl.pdf

Comment: @PaulK But I'm not sure how, because the generalization talks about extension to some neighbourhood, and in the theorem that I quoted we continue $ f $  to a specific set

Comment: @LéoS. That's not true, some analytic functions cannot be extended to all of $\mathbb{C}$.  There may be singularities or a boundary beyond which they cannot be extended. (However if there is an extension, it is unique, assuming the domain is open and connected.)

Comment: @JairTaylor thanks for the correction, I should have been more careful. (Should I delete my comment in such situations?)

Comment: @LéoS. It's up to you if you want to delete the comment. I personally don't mind this kind of back-and-forth discussion.

Comment: Okay, I'll leave it then.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R_1$ be a side of $R$ and $S_1$ the side of $S$ with $f(R_1) = S_1$. If $R_1$ is parallel to the $y$-axis, consider $g(z) := f(i z)$. Similarly, if $S_1$ is parallel to the $y$-axis, consider $g(z) := i f(z)$. Hence, without loss of generality: $R_1, S_1$ are parallel to the $x$-axis. Now consider $g(z) := f(z + a) + b$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $R_1, S_1$ lie on the $x$-axis. Now you can apply the reflection principle to obtain a function on a larger rectangle which still satisfies the assumption with larger rectangles $R', S'$.

Comment: Are you assuming that the function is analytic on the edges as well? If it is only continuous then Morera's theorem will do the trick. Not sure if it is not assumed continuous.